# Secondary voltage referred to the primary

Tags: transformer

I am studying transformers and I am not completely understanding a basic detail, but it is annoying me.

When we draw the equivalent circuit of a transformer, why is the secondary voltage referred to the primary written as \$V_{2}'=\frac{N_1}{N_2}V_2\$ ?

Comment: What do V2 and V'2 represent?

Comment: \$V_2\$ is the voltage on secondary and \$V_{2}'\$ is the voltage \$V_2\$ referred to the primary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These currents --- in primary or secondary --- develop a flux in the core that is common to all windings. The response of each winding to the common flux is proportional to #turns in that winding. Thus a transformer is a self-regulating machine, with back-electromotive-force (back EMF) providing the negative feedback.